# Каким образом можно парсить SPA сайты?

Tags: javascript, парсер, spa

Нужно спарсить инфу с сайта.
Проблема в том, что он одностраничный (SPA).
Если отключить скрипты, то мы получаем только пустую страницу с несколькими скриптами.
При входе на сайт он отправляет запрос и получает html с другими скриптами.
Короче непонятно мне как это сделать пока.

Сайт работает через meteor как я понял.

Если кто занимался подобным, подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Смысл парсить SPA сайт, если можно просто посмотреть откуда он грузит инфу, которую вы хотите получить, и брать её напрямую оттуда? Поииследуйте запросы, которые с этого сайта уходят, найдите интересующий вас и вуаля. Получаете данные сразу в удобном формате

Comment: Так и делаю сейчас, разбираюсь.  
Просто думал вдруг есть какие-то еще способы.

Comment: Есть. Selenium, расширения-парсеры.. но это из пушки по воробьям в большинстве случаев

Comment: Selenium тоже рассматривал, насчет пушки согласен